# Converting a string to date in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, date-conversion

from a file i read a string like this: "Nov  4 07:27:27 2022 GMT". I try to convert this to german Datetime, later it will be stored in a SQL-table.
Currently i do the conversion like this:

```
MyTmpString = "Nov  4 07:27:27 2022 GMT";
string format;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
format = "MMM  d HH:mm:ss yyyy GMT";
try {
    Datum_von = DateTime.ParseExact(MyTmpString, format, provider);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", MyTmpString, Datum_von.ToString());
}
catch (FormatException) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", MyTmpString);
}
```

This works for that specific case. I already run into problems if day as more than 1 digit. In this case i have to use a format like this:

```
format = "MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy GMT";
```

May be the string occurs in more variants currently i dont know. i dont want to create a format and try-catch for every possibility. Iam looking for a kind of universal conversionmethod to have a german date at the end.
What should i do here, do you have any recommendations?

Thank you,
Hans

Comment: You will need a list of all possible formats to make this robust. If your data file all of a sudden contains completely different data formats, it is even possible that there's no correct solution for the problem.

Comment: The "d" [should](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dSpecifier) match "one or two digits for day"

Comment: If the string could be (e.g.) both `dd-mm-yyyy` and `mm-dd-yyyy`, there's no way to resolve the ambiguity for values like `01-02-2023`. The best you can do is force the source to adopt one format (preferably `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` in UTC or local time or with a time zone if necessary). The second best thing if that's not possible is to accept a *specific* set of formats only, that are not ambiguous with each other -- `ParseExact` has an overload that accepts an array of formats.

Comment: @Hans Kesting
Ohh, seems to be true. I was testing and i got an error, but the error in format was the whitespace. 1 digit day has 2 spaces between Name of day and day. If day has 2 digits there is only one space.  So i could do a replace 2 spaces into one in datestring to have a kind of normalisation and may be its possible to use same formatstring.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As Hans Kesting suggests, ParseExact's  `-d` format shouldn't care if days are 1 or 2 digits. Your problem is the extra spaces.
Also instead of relying on catching an exception, which is expensive performance-wise, you should use TryParseExact. It even has an option that allows you to ignore superfluous white space in the string:

```cs
var myTmpString = "Nov    14    07:27:27   2022 GMT";
// Or var myTmpString = "Nov    4    07:27:27   2022 GMT";

System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string format = "MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy GMT";
bool result = DateTime.TryParseExact(myTmpString, format, provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out DateTime datum_von);
if (result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", myTmpString, datum_von.ToString());
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", myTmpString);
}
```

If TryParseExact returns true, you can use the value from the `out` parameter, otherwise parsing has failed.

Comment: Thank you, looks promising. Will try it tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you, i tried it and it works with.